# mapping objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping

I'm trying to create an object with these two a and b, first one's header columns are corresponding to another object's keys.
For Example:

```js
a =[{  name: 'CreatedDateTime', header: 'Tarih' },
    {  name: 'Name', header: 'Adi' }]

b= [{ CreatedDateTime:"10.1.2021" },{Name:"Merve"}]
```

The output should be like this:

```js
c=[{Tarih:"10.1.2021" , Adi:"Merve" }]
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Why is `c` an array?

Comment: That's not what I asked you. **Why** is it an array? What determines the number of elements in it? Right now it only has one element which appears to be produced by combining `a` and `b`

Comment: Will there always be one element in the object of each element in `b` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the `a` array to the object you want by

1. Iterating each entry and extracting the `name` and `header` properties
2. Using the `header` as the object key
3. Using the matching index from `b` (if it exists) and extracting the `name` property as the value

```js
const a = [{"name":"CreatedDateTime","header":"Tarih"},{"name":"Name","header":"Adi"}]
const b = [{"CreatedDateTime":"10.1.2021"},{"Name":"Merve"}]

const c = a.reduce((o, { header, name }, i) => ({
  ...o,
  [ header ]: b[i]?.[name] // use optional-chaining in case it doesn't exist
}), {})

console.log(c)
```

This produces an object. If you really need that to be a single-element array, just wrap it, ie

```js
const cArray = [ c ] // no idea why
```

Comment: oh im sorry know i get it what you mean. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Phil provided a generalized solution already, here is a non-generalized solution maybe easier to understand the basics:

```js
var a = [{  name: 'CreatedDateTime', header: 'Tarih' },{  name: 'Name', header: 'Adi' }]

var b = [{ CreatedDateTime:"10.1.2021" },{Name:"Merve"}]

var c = {};
c[a[0].header] = b[0][a[0].name]
c[a[1].header] = b[1][a[1].name]
console.log("c: ", c)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `b[0][a[0].name]` / `b[1][a[1].name]`? Otherwise, you're only using half the data in `a`

Comment: Yes it would, edited the snippet with your suggestion.

Comment: Throw in a `for` loop and you won't have to keep adding new lines for each new entry in `a`